# Decimal Save not Working in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, decimal

In my controller I am running the following code:

```
  @place = Place.new :latitude => params[:lat].to_d, :longitude=>params[:lng].to_d
  puts @place.latitude
  puts @place.longitude
  @place.save!
  puts @place.latitude
  puts @place.longitude
```

And the output in my server log is as follows:

```
37.865338226051534
-122.25851513692476
37.09024
-95.712891
```

I understand the fact that it is being rounded, as I used precision 15 scale 10 decimals. But why is it changing the number to a completely different value?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the library I was using was limiting the size during a calculation.